# Passing Cario's dir to meson

Tags: compiling, epiphany, cairo

While trying to build epiphany I received:

> Run-time dependency cairo found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

> meson.build:80:0: ERROR: Dependency "cairo" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

Then I tried to pass cairo to it:`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/ meson ..`

The error messages persisted.

On another post I say someone suggesting to use `setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/ meson ..`

However, setenv doesn't work on my terminal

The final part of meson.log.txt:

> Pkg-config binary for 1 is not cached.
> Pkg-config binary missing from cross or native file, or env var undefined.
> Trying a default Pkg-config fallback at pkg-config
> Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.22)
> Determining dependency 'iso-codes' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion iso-codes` -> 0
> 3.12.1
> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --cflags iso-codes` -> 0

> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> env[PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS]: 1
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs iso-codes` -> 0

> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs iso-codes` -> 0

> Run-time dependency iso-codes found: YES 3.12.1
> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --variable=prefix iso-codes` -> 0
> /usr
> Got pkgconfig variable prefix : /usr
> Pkg-config binary for 1 is cached.
> Determining dependency 'cairo' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
> env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/
> Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion cairo` -> 1

> CMake binary for 1 is not cached
> CMake binary missing from cross or native file, or env var undefined.
> Trying a default CMake fallback at cmake
> Found CMake: /usr/local/bin/cmake (3.19.2)
> Extracting basic cmake information
> CMake Toolchain: Calling CMake once to generate the compiler state
> Calling CMake (['/usr/local/bin/cmake']) in /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/meson-private/**CMake_compiler_info** with:
>
> - "--trace-expand"
> - "--trace-format=json-v1"
> - "--no-warn-unused-cli"
> - "--trace-redirect=cmake_trace.txt"
> - "-G"
> - "Ninja"
> - "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/meson-private/**CMake_compiler_info**/CMakeMesonTempToolchainFile.cmake"
> - "."
>   WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
>   Try CMake generator: auto
>   Calling CMake (['/usr/local/bin/cmake']) in /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/meson-private/cmake_cairo with:
> - "--trace-expand"
> - "--trace-format=json-v1"
> - "--no-warn-unused-cli"
> - "--trace-redirect=cmake_trace.txt"
> - "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/meson-private/cmake_cairo/CMakeMesonToolchainFile.cmake"
> - "."
>   -- Module search paths:    ['/', '/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cmake-3.19.2-Linux-x86_64', '/opt', '/usr', '/usr/local']
>   -- CMake root:             /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cmake-3.19.2-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.19
>   -- CMake architectures:    []
>   -- CMake lib search paths: ['lib', 'lib32', 'lib64', 'libx32', 'share']
>   Preliminary CMake check failed. Aborting.
>   Run-time dependency cairo found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

> meson.build:80:0: ERROR: Dependency "cairo" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

I have no idea why pkg-config is not finding it. Yet, cmake is not looking into Cairo's dir, since I didn't pass anything to it. probably there is a way to so. The problem is thatit is being called indirectly by meson.

Comment: So what does `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/ /usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion cairo` return?

Comment: @steeldriver. It returns: "Package gobject-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gobject-2.0', required by 'cairo', not found"

Comment: I guess that means I should pass the dir where all the glib's pc files are located (and perhaps the dirs where the other cairo's dependencies are located). The questions is why the hell didn't meson inform me of that?

Comment: Neh, it didn't work. I tried: PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.32.0/lib/pkgconfig/ meson ..